# How to compile app to work on several Glibc versions

Tags: c++, glibc, dynamic-linking

How can i compile application to work on all 2.X Glibc versions? Now i compile on machine with 2.7 GLibc version, but when i start app where glibc version is 2.5, i have an error:

```
./server: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.7' not found (required by ./server)
```

How can i compile app that will work on all 2.X versions?

Compile command:

```
g++  -o newserver  test.cpp ... -lboost_system -lboost_thread -std=c++0x
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to build on a machine with the oldest glibc among those you're going to support. With linux machines, you may even take a complete installation and transfer it into a `chroot`ed environment on your machine: this way, there is no need to downgrade *your* workplace.

I would be glad to see a more convenient solution in other answers (if it will be *more convenient* indeed: anything involving GCC rebuild doesn't qualify, IMHO).

Comment: so, if i compile app with glibc 2.2 for example, it will work for 2.7 too? If yes, can you please, help me, how can i do this?

Comment: Yes, if you compile for glibc 2.2, it will work for 2.7. And the easiest way to do so is to install a *system* which has glibc 2.2. It's up to you whether to install into chrooted environment, to a virtual machine, or to a physical machine -- choose what you want.

Comment: @Breakdown, yes, exactly. The easiest way is to install an old version of GNU/Linux in a VM. (Installing glibc manually, into a chroot or elsewhere, is hard. Installing a complete distro into a VM is pretty easy)

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert but it occurs to me that, if the application need to run with glibc 2.5, then it must confine itself to features that are available in 2.5, and nothing thereafter. In other words, restrain using features introduced in 2.6 or later. Will that help?

If you *really* need features from glibc 2.7, then make it an *explicit requirement* for the target systems. You can put some code to check the glibc version of the system it is running on and if the available version is lower than the required version, then print/log a comprehensive message and gracefully exit.

However, if you want to cast your net wide, i.e. plan to run your application on wide spectrum of systems, then resorting the usage to a lower version (as sketched in para 1) might turn out to be more fruitful.

Comment: Generally, it does not. Things get fixed or altered somehow, and suddenly your old well-known symbols are `GLIBC_2.7`.